# Laravel Routing - How to pass a variable to subroutes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm using the group logic to filter the admin section of my website. I have a routing like this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    $datas['user']['email'] = Auth::user()->email;

    Route::get('admin/dashboard', function() {
        return View::make('admin/dashboard')->with(array('datas' => $datas));
    });
    //other routes...
});
```

How to make `$datas` available to all routes that are included in my group ?

Comment: Have a look at this answer. [View Composer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27852897/2888851)

Answer (score 0):

You can share variables:

```
View::share('datas', $datas);
return View::make('admin/dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that you'd like to include `$datas` in every *route*, you can make use of the `use` keyword:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    $datas['user']['email'] = Auth::user()->email;

    Route::get('admin/dashboard', function() use ($datas)
    {
        return View::make('admin/dashboard')->with(array('datas' => $datas));
    });
});
```

You can learn about the `use` keyword [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10692942/1626250).